# Oauth for non public api

Tags: api, rest, security, oauth

I'm planning to use oauth for securing api exposed to web only to be used by the applications we create. Is oauth an overkill. Can someone recommend something else if you think it is an overkill. We secure the channel with TLS too.

Comment: OAuth (2) is a light-weight protocol, so I don’t see why this would be overkill. Sure, you don’t need to implement a mechanism to register applications etc. but that only makes it less of a hassle.

Comment: But in addition to authentication we may also need access key management and since we aren't going to handle delegated authentication, I was a little concerned that I may be overlooking something for implementing authentication. So do you think may be I can go ahead with oauth using say Apache Oltu

Comment: I agree with the poster: Oauth carries a lot of complexity with it in terms of implementing it securely ([Oauth threat model](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-threatmodel-01) is 71 pages) and in terms of understanding it.  Especially if it is your own server that will handle identity, authorisation, and resources, then Oauth 2 feels like overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

[OAuth](http://oauth.net/2/) is a protocol designed to allow an application to access resources via an API even if the resource owner (user) is not present. That doesn't mean you can't use it when the user is there to provide access to your APIs. It should not be hard to find an implementation for your platform.

Making the API private to your application will work just fine if your application is a web application in which you can keep a secret (the client credentials).

If your application is a JavaScript application accessing the API from the browser (or even a native application), you can't keep secrets in those clients.

You'll have to trust on authenticating your users to access your API.

Comment: Could you please clarify the relevance of your first paragraph to his question.  I do not see that his question is anything about the presence of the user but instead is about who is developing the client applications, but maybe I misunderstand.  Also, the question is whether oauth is **overkill**, and I do not see that you have answered that.  Just to clarify, right now I am not challenging the correctness of your reply, instead I am saying that I do not see the relevance of your reply to his question.

Comment: I'm just clarifying what problem OAuth is intended to solve. Whether it is overkill in the OP situation is very much opinion based and not suitable for SO.